# Processing posted data in Express + Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am attempting to capture the information that is being sent from a form in Express and Node.js. Here are the relevant contents of my app.js and index.hjs:

**app.js**

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(function (req, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain')
  res.write('you posted:\n')
  res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body, null, 2))
})
```

**index.hjs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
    <form method="post" action="/">
      <input type="test" name="field1">
      <input type="test" name="field2">
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

When attempting to submit the form on http://expressserver.domain:3000, I receive a 404 error. Does anyone have any ideas on what the issue is and point me in the right direction?

Comment: why `action="#"`? this isn't HTML 3.2, and you're not posting to "the top of this page". Omit the action if it's on the same URL, or keep it in and use a proper URL if it's to a target different from the current URL.

Comment: That has been fixed and isn't intended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a really good example here: http://runnable.com/U0sU598vXio2uD-1/example-reading-form-input-with-express-4-0-and-body-parser-for-node-js which works.

Comment: If you can, use [formidable](https://www.npmjs.org/package/formidable) module instead of body-parser. For one, body-parser does not support multi-part forms :).

Comment: Isn't it file upload focused though?

Comment: Here's another [reason](http://andrewkelley.me/post/do-not-use-bodyparser-with-express-js.html) :).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `app.use`, have a real POST route.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.json(req.body);
});
```

You need an actual route for it to kick in, and you want `.post`, not `.use`, because the latter is for all possible HTTP verbs, which means it'll try to access `req.body` for things that never have one (GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, etc) and crash your script.

Comment: Right, this is a better method than mine. `app.use` can point to a module which contains the `get()` and `post()` methods if you had them on the namespace.

Comment: I've replaced `app.use` with the code you've provided. When submitting the form I am still not receiving any output in console. Is there anything else I need in the `index.hjs` file?

Comment: looking at the HTML, your form doesn't actually have any values associated with it either, so try adding an `<input type="hidden" value="TESTING!" name="htext">` and then posting. `req.body` should now have an `htext` property at least.